# How to cancel an action hooked to untrash_post? or any hook

Tags: hooks, actions, trash, customization

I want to do the following in a plugin: 
- hook to `untrash_post`with a custom function
- do some checking inside custom function
- cancel actual post restoring (untrashing)

I've tried with `remove_action` but doesn't seem to work.
Can you point me into the right direction?

Code sample:

```
add_action( 'untrash_post', array( __CLASS__, 'static_untrash_handler' ) );
```

.....

```
public static function static_untrash_handler( $post ) {
```

`// check stuff`

`// prevent post from being restored. How ?`

`}`

Should I return something to 'break the cycle' ?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Can you just update the post status to trashed in that hook? What does it report as the status in the handler?

Comment: You can't set it to trashed in that hook, because it'll just get immediately set back, but maybe you can hook `untrashed_post` instead, which runs immediately after it's untrashed instead of before. [See it in source here](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.5.1/wp-includes/post.php#L2422).

Answer (score 1):

`untrash_post` fires before the untrashing happens. If you want to undo the untrashing, you should use the `untrashed_post` action which fires after it.

Comment: Oh yes, this is a solution but I was thinking at something more 'optimized' since this will be redundant: untrash post -> check stuff -> trash post. This means more queries to the WP database. Beside this, it will do it. Thank you!

Comment: you can always try make checks before `wp_untrash_post` is called to prevent it, but it is much harder to cover all possible paths

Answer (score 1):

its a little clumsy but you could combine what you are already doing with the 'untrashed_post' hook which fires **after** the post has been untrashed

here are the rough steps:

- use **'untrash_post'** hook to do your checking (like you are now)
- if you need to cancel the untrash, store a flag in post meta with ie. *update_post_meta( $post_id, 'keep_trashed', true );*
- use **'untrashed_post'** to check if the post should be retrashed with *get_post_meta( $post_id, 'keep_trashed', true );*
- if so, use *wp_trash_post( $post_id  );* to retrash the post
- dump the post meta *delete_post_meta( $post_id, 'keep_trashed' );*

Comment: I'm thinking at optimization and this solution will add more queries. It will work but with a cost :) Thanks!

Comment: agreed .. i think it would be better if the parent function 'wp_untrash_post' actually checked for a return value from the 'untrash_post' hook and provided an option to exit the function at that point. That said unless your users will be doing this a lot, its not such a big optimization issue.

Comment: Indeed, that I was expecting to be the behavior but untrashed_post hook will do the trick!